# getting id from child table to the parent table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreign-keys, user-input

using php pdo ive built a very basic image upload form to learn image uploading. I have two tables a post table and an image table. With this you can create a post containing some text and image and after submitting it displays those. The problem is I cannot get the image to display it just displays a broken image.

I set up a foreign key in the database so that the id of the image is added to a column titled image_id in the post table, but I cannot figure out how to populate the image_id column in the post table with the corresponding image id. if I manually type in the image id on the image_id column the image does display. any tips would be helpful I was thinking i need to do something different with the image_id variable below

```
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$date_uploaded=date("Y-m-d");
$location="upload/".$file_name;

$title    = $_POST['title'];
$content  = $_POST['content'];
$image_id = $_POST['image_id'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO post(title, content, image_id) VALUES (:title, :content,         :image_id)");


$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':content', $content);
$stmt->bindParam(':image_id', $image_id);
$stmt->execute();`
```

Thank you this is functioning now. This is the updated version based on the advise. is this more of the correct idea?

```
$data = [
           'file' => $file_name,
           'alt' => $file_temp,
                ];
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO images (file, alt)  VALUES (:file, :alt)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($data);
        
        $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        $title    = $_POST['title'];
        $content  = $_POST['content'];
           
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO post(title, content, image_id) VALUES (:title, :content, :image_id)");

        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
        $stmt->bindParam(':content', $content);
        $stmt->bindParam(':image_id', $last_id);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Why you're getting the id from  $_POST and not the actual insert? I mean, why it's even  $_POST? How it makes sense to get image id from  $_POST?

Comment: that's where I am stuck I put that just while researching how to get the image_id inserted. I have tried putting below that code $image_id = $pdo->lastInsertId(); but I cant figure out how to then use that to update the post table with the image_id

Comment: Well although you *can* update the post table, the usual way, using UPDATE query, I would suggest to do it the other way round: first insert into image table, get the Id and then insert into post table using that id.